# Cannot draw on surfaceview onDraw

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

Hi i am using SurfaceView to draw on canvas.When i am using like this

```
canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 5, paint); //it is drawing fine
```

while i am using like this :

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 5, paint); //it's not drawing.x,y being some points on screen and they are floats.
```

Any help

Comment: Post some more code, it seems likely that x and y are not initialized properly. Also, try setting x = 100 and y=100 just before the `drawCircle()` call.

Comment: yes i am drawing to circles.one using 100,100 and one using x,y.And also i am printing x,y values,they are non-zero floating point values.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your x and y coordinate are positive and inside the bounds of your view:

```
x >= 0 && x < canvas.getWidth() && y >= 0 && y < canvas.getHeight()
```

Comment: i am 100% certain.put this in comment.this is not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
         @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(1);
            canvas.clipRect(new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
            canvas.save();      
        }
        float x,y;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            x=event.getX();
            y=event.getY();
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: its working good for me .. if still its not working for u,  check ur x and y updating or not, else you are drawing some other layer (bitmap) which is overriding ur circle..

Comment: my x and y are there sure for that and there is no layer.

Comment: ok.. are you calling the invalidate(); function in ur on touch method

Answer (score 0):

Some types of views don't redraw themselves by default. If you want it do do so, implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback` in your view and add this:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}
```